# Harbor mutil-version images

Tags: kubernetes, harbor

I am new to the private docker registry "Harbor". Just want to know how to push multi versions of  same images to the same project. I am trying to keep my latest image with the tag "latest" since I want to always use the latest one when k8s pod pulls from the registry while at the same time, keep the past versions in Harbor, any advise?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no such thing as "multi-version images", you just push the same image twice with different tags.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the approach of symlinks.

Tagging an image is metadata operation. Multiple tags can be created on a single image.

Upon every new build, assign a tag with build number and for the latest build which should be referred by k8s pod, add additional tag “latest”. This will keep the original tag info where multi-version images can be referred and only latest is used by the app.